# PHP session cookie - security concern

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I'm using a session cookie to display a category id from one page to another in Wordpress using the following code:

```
<?php if(is_product_category()) {
    session_start();
    $cat_obj = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
    $thiscat_id = $cat_obj->term_id;
    $_SESSION['category'] = $thiscat_id;
} ?>

<?php if(is_product()) {
    session_start();
}
?>

<div <?php if(is_product()) { ?> data-cat="<?php echo $_SESSION['category']; ?>" <?php } ?> id="content" class="site-content">
```

However, after reading up on Sessions, i've discovered that they can be a security risk if done incorrectly.

I'm just wondering if the above code has any flaws which could effect security?

Comment: Seriously, if you store a category in your session only, how could that ever be a security risk?

Comment: For code review we can use following https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks @maio290, i did originally think the code shouldn't be a security risk but just wanted to get it checked incase I was missing anything.

Comment: Just for information : session and cookie are not the same things.

Comment: What security concern are you inquiring about? Someone could potentially  force the ID and get another person's category. That doesn't sound like a big issue to me though. If that is the question though see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/81519/session-hijacking-through-sessionid-brute-forcing-possible

Comment: Security is not a concern here. But whether this actually and reliably achieves what you want, might be a different question. For example if the user has your site open in multiple tabs, the result would still be the same in all of them, because they share the session. (Whether that is what you want or not, dunno, because your description lacks an explanation of _why_ you are doing this in the first place.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, its only a security risk if it fails to protect an asset with some value - the value of the asset is not clear from your question. If, for instance you have a "category" which allows admin actions on your site, then there may be risks.

Yes, there are big security issues around sessions - but most of them have very little to do with your PHP code but rather with the PHP and webserver configuration:

- session ids must always be changed when authentication state changes (login *and* logout)
- unless the site is accessed via HTTPS *and* the session cookie has the secure flag, its trivial to hijack a session
- null sessions must trigger a new session id and a default session state
- session cookies should by httponly
- on a shared host, session data should be encrypted using a key *not* persisted on the host
- session data should never be accessible to the end user
- session ids must not be predictable